# Validity of cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

`The function
 F 
(
x
) = 1+sin(
x
) is not a valid cumulative distribution function. Why not?`

What properties make a `Cumulative Distribution Function` valid? Ive heard something about it being `non descending` what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Intuitively, the CDF is the integral of the PDF.  Since the probability density is never negative, the CDF cannot decrease.

Comment: @EricTowers The result of the function cannot decrease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CDF is a monotonically nondecreasing function, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 1$.  From this, $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}$, the probability density function, is everywhere positive.

Alternatively, given a PDF, $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, one may define the associated CDF via $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$.  Again, one finds the properties listed above.

This can be made more convoluted, but the essential features are still present.

Comment: ...the PDF, when it exists...

Comment: Well, yeah.  But that might be a higher level of detail than the question entails.

Comment: Adding "when it exists" involves no "higher level of details", if you ask me, only it makes correct a statement which is not as it is.

Comment: @Did: Have you read the question?

Comment: ?? I wonder what you are trying to achieve with this comment.

Comment: @Did:  To point out that the level of detail in the answer matches the level of detail in the question.  We could wish for crazy precise questions that would justify crazy precise answers, but that's not always what we get.

Comment: To me, answers should be more precise than questions, especially when questions are not precise. This is called teaching, if I remember. By the way, this is the second time you confuse "detailed" with precise and/or correct.

Comment: @Did:  And I take the position that detail, precision, or correctness overwhelming that in the question leads to more confusion that resolution.

Comment: "Detail", again? You are not listening... So be it.